# What sort of actions can I take to make printer mapping less painful for all involved?

Tags: ip, hostname, network-printer, print-server

I currently work on/sort of manage a very large network. We employ the use of a print server to make some things easier for end users, but I'm sure you all know that that comes with its own issues.

I was recently namedropped into trying to find some way to make printers map based on hostname rather than IP address, as when a certain server fails/goes down (which is somewhat often, due to current migration efforts), printers drop off of the print server entirely or have their IP addresses changed, which messes up the current mapping system.

The main issue I've run into is that many of the solutions I've seen that can make printer mapping and other such things easier are changes that I wouldn't enact myself; they'd have to go through and be approved by a much higher authority, which takes quite some time.

That said, though, what sort of ideas/solutions might be best? Users employ many, many different kinds of printers without rhyme or reason, and pushing out printers through GPO isn't exactly feasible, as machines are constantly being moved out and new ones brought in while users are likewise constantly in motion.

Any help/advice/ideas would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't or shouldn't use GPO to deploy the printers. It's made for this exact purpose. If nothing else, you could just use a "shotgun" approach and give the users more printers than they need, if the company approves it.

Comment: You probably already know, but in AD you can make *Security Groups* for accounting, marketing, sales, etc. and add your users, then set permissions to the printer by said SG. That way only the appropriate people or machines can print. Combine this with GPO printer deployment and you're all set. It doesn't matter if the machines or users change, you can just add or remove from the SG's.

Comment: The main issue here is that we (the "administrators") don't have the rights to create/delete/modify GPOs. They have be routed through other channels for approval for denial, followed by a lengthy implementation process.

EDIT: With a network of quite literally thousands of users/systems under my umbrella, "just" adding/removing individuals from security groups isn't entirely feasible, either. I wish it were, because I enjoy the organization it gives, but it simply isn't.

Comment: I see. I'm from the SMB world and am used to a lot of autonomy (even full rein) over my network, but I understand that is delegated away in enterprise. I suppose you'll need some kind of "print serverless" solution but I have no idea what that would be. I have seen such solutions advertised at conventions though.

Comment: I'll look into it. I appreciate the help.